# Rank System in Skype Application

Tags: c#, skype, bots, skype4com

So as some of you may know, I'm currently working on a Skype "bot" sort of application. As of now i have a lot of commands implemented and it's working wonderfully. I'm just trying to figure out how I can add a sort of "rank" system, and limit certain commands to specific users. What method does SKYPE4COM offer that I can use to check for a user's actual Skype username? 
Please help,
S

Answer (score 0):

There is `IUser.Handle` (from Skype4COM Documentation):

> This command queries/sets the Skypename of the user.

Comment: How would I use IUser.Handle to get the usernames of everyone in a chat group, and only allow the bot to listen to certain users?

Comment: @user1356292 There is `IChat.Members` property which gets a collection of `IUser`'s.